# Compare values in array?

Tags: ruby

I need to compare the values inside the array.

For instance, my array is:

```
[18, 1, 113, 103, 1100, 909, 94, 67, 61]
```

I need to compare each value, something like `18->1`, `1->113`, `113->103` and so on.

Comment: So, do you need to sort the values? What is the purpose in comparing them? Otherwise you can just use two simple loops to go through the array and compare them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what sort of comparison you want, but this will walk through the array, comparing consecutive elements:

```
puts [
  18, 1, 113, 103, 1100, 909, 94, 67, 61
].each_cons(2).map{ |a, b| a <=> b }
```

Which outputs:

```
1
-1
1
-1
1
1
1
1
```

The comparison operator `<=>` is used for sorting to compare two values. It returns -1 when `a < b`, 0 when `a == b` and 1 when `a > b`.

So, that tells us that `18 > 1`, `1 < 113`, `113 > 103`, `103 < 1100`, and all the rest are in descending order.

Replace `<=>` with whatever comparison you need.